# kendo.data.DataSource.hasChanges() method true after save

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I've configured my `kendo` grid to call a custom service upon clicking "Save Changes" button.  Function call is as follows:

```
saveChanges: function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $scope.updateLineItems(e);

    // Clear red triangles on edited cells
    $scope.grid.refresh();
}
```

Does calling `preventDefault()` prevent the grid from resetting the return value of `hasChanges()`?  When I make a change the value is true.  I was hoping that after clicking "Save Changes" it would revert to false, but it does not.  I tried adding a line after the grid refresh to manually run the `cancelChanges()` method, but that undid the changes in the grid display.

Is there any other method to take the grid out of edit mode?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> Does calling preventDefault() prevent the grid from resetting the return value of hasChanges()?

Calling the `preventDefault()` does not prevent from resetting the return value. The `hasChanges()` are determined by the `dirty` property. In your `update` operation, you should return a success call such as `e.success()` for the grid to know that changes have been applied.

You can also check their doc: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/datasource/crud#update-local

Hope this helps!